# oVirt - FQDN issue

Tags: dns, centos8, fqdn, ovirt

I am currently testing oVirt to see if it match with my needs. Only at the installation and initialization step, I'm blocked by DNS resolution from the Web GUI when I fill in "engine VM FQDN" by ovirt-engine.example.com and "FQDN host" by engine-host.example .com. Despite these declared domains I still have the error "The address proposed for this host does not resolves locally"
I specify that my "/etc/hosts" is like this:

- ::1     localhost       localhost.localdomain   localhost6
  localhost6.localdomain6
- 127.0.0.1       localhost       localhost.localdomain   localhost4      localhost4.localdomain4
- 127.0.0.1       ovirt-engine.example.com
- 127.0.0.1       engine-host.example.com

And I'm on Centos 8.
And DNS resolution when pinging, works fine.
Why is it not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosts names can not resolves to localhost. Ensure your host hypervisor resolves to its forwardable ip address and assign the **ovirt-engine.example.com** to another ip on the same network.

Your oVirt Engine will be deployed as a virtual machine and it won't be bounded anyway with the physical hosts on which the installation is started. You can add any additional physical hosts and migrate the Engine VM on it. Therefore, the name **engine-host.example.com** is misleading imho.

Since you're not using an external DNS server (which is strongly encouraged), rember to expand the **Advanced** section and select the **Edit Hosts File** check box to add entries for the Engine VM and the physical host to the virtual machine’s `/etc/hosts` file.